# Display page urls as titles

Tags: zend-framework2

What I am trying to do is have the page display the current route it's on (for example Dashboard » Admin » Another Page but I can only get it to display the Dashboard and then the Admin title. (with Zend Framework 2)

This is what I am using to display the url of the page Dashboard » ucfirst(str_replace("/", "", $this->url())); (in php tags obviously)

I was wondering if there was a way to display a optional route after the url so it would show up as Dashboard » Admin » Blog

Thanks

(Update)
This is what I have in my config/autoload/global.php

```
'navigation' => array(
'default' => array(
    'admin' => array(
        'label' => 'Dashboard',
        'route' => 'admin',
        'pages' => array(
            'home' => array(
                'label' => 'Admin',
                'route' => 'admin',
            ),

            'blog' => array(
                 'label' => 'Blog',
                 'route' => 'admin/blog',
            ),

        ),
    ),
),  
),
and this is in my application's layout:

$this->navigation('Navigation')->breadcrumbs()->setSeparator(PHP_EOL . '&raquo;');
```

but it is still only showing Dashboard >> Admin and not the blog breadcrumb text. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You must tell which Zend Framework version you are using? 1 or 2

Comment: (with Zend Framework 2)

Comment: Ok I see, you want achieve what they call zend  Dynamic Breadcrumbs, You can do this with help of Zend Framework navigation. Check this out. http://adam.lundrigan.ca/2012/07/25/quick-and-dirty-zf2-zendnavigation/ this may help you.

Comment: Yes I tried doing that but I could not get it to work. Is there an alternative?

Comment: I am now busy doing something else. This shouldn't be difficult. I may post it for you, if i come to that. But you can get it as think on the Net.

Comment: Well, the routing structure is giving me issues, that's all.

Comment: I got it to work, however it still only shows one page and not a subpage and I followed everything on that site..